# How to make root-created files accessible to normal users?

Tags: root-access, file-permissions

My device is running Android 8.0, rooted using Magisk as the `su` manager. I log into it using SimpleSSHD.

I'm trying to do some actions which require root access, and in the process I'm creating some files to be later used by normal users. But for some reason what I'm used to in "classical" Linux distributions doesn't appear to work: root-created files can't be read by normal users, whatever `chown`/`chgrp`/`chmod` actions I try. See the following session:

```
$ su -c "echo hello > file.txt; chown $(whoami) file.txt; chgrp $(whoami) file.txt; chmod a+r file.txt"
$ cat file.txt
cat: file.txt: Permission denied
$ echo readable > my.txt
$ su -c 'cp -a my.txt my-copy.txt'
$ cat my-copy.txt
cat: my-copy.txt: Permission denied
$ ls -l *.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 u0_a182 u0_a182 6 2018-08-20 15:21 file.txt
-rw------- 1 u0_a182 u0_a182 9 2018-08-20 15:23 my-copy.txt
-rw------- 1 u0_a182 u0_a182 9 2018-08-20 15:22 my.txt
$ whoami
u0_a182
```

What's happening here? Why are permission bits, owner and group ignored for files I created as root? How to properly change owner to normal user?

Comment: Could you please describe how did you set up SSH server on Android phone? Я тоже хочу)

Comment: @Suncatcher simply installed SimpleSSHD, and its config is trivial (works out of the box, just be sure to connect via port 2222 instead of the usual 22, and then enter the password it prints in its activity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses SELinux to manage file access. The files created by root and non-root users differ by SELinux context:

```
$ ls -lZ *.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 u0_a182 u0_a182 u:object_r:app_data_file:s0           6 2018-08-20 16:01 file.txt
-rw------- 1 u0_a182 u0_a182 u:object_r:app_data_file:s0           9 2018-08-20 16:01 my-copy.txt
-rw------- 1 u0_a182 u0_a182 u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 9 2018-08-20 16:01 my.txt
```

To make the file really belong to the non-root user, one has to set the correct SELinux context:

```
$ su -c 'chcon u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 file.txt'
$ cat file.txt
hello
```